# Set ImageView from SDcard to match_parent height?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

So I  have an `ActionDialog` that saves a signature. When I set the `ImageView` to the new captured signature it is way too tall. Below I will illustrate the problem

Right now at default the screen looks like this

(textview)-(--edittext--)-(space)-
(textview)-(--edittext--)-(space)-
(textview)-(imageview)-(button)-

after the user clicks the button it asks for a signature, saves the signature, then replaces the default `ImageView` with the new `bitmap`. However it ends up looking like this

(textview)-(--edittext--)-(space)-
(textview)-(--edittext--)-(space)-
(textview)-(imageview)-(button)-

I'm unsure why this is happening. Here is the `XML Layout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/twoglobe_line"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/sigll3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/sigll1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/print_name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/sigll2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/signature"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sig_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:src="@drawable/sig" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signature"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/sign" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I would like to make it so that the new `bitmap` is the same height as the `button` and `textview` next to it. Or as much as possible. 
Thanks for any help you can offer

Comment: wrap_content for imageview

Comment: Please explain what you mean with "keep the original height as much as possible", whether to the height of the default image before or the height of the new image? If you want the height of the default image, I think you should set a fixed height of the `ImageView`.

Comment: @JRowan I wish it was that simple. I tried that, and tried it again, unfortunately I believe the default height of the bitmap is too tall thus it's the same result.

Comment: scale the bitmap before you put it in then

Comment: @BornToCode I mean I would like it to match the height of the TextView and Button on the left and right side of it. So maybe 15dp to 20dp, I'd have to play with it to figure out the exact height. I'm wary of hard coding it though because of different screen resolutions

Comment: hold on, check this out you could use this

Comment: maybe the code i posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this to get the pixels to scale the image to according to the textview or whatever per device, then scale the bitmap accordingly

```
public static int dpToPixels(Context context, float dp) {
    final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return (int) (dp * scale + 0.5f);
}
```

then in your code after this like this

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mysig
                                .getAbsolutePath());
bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp,bmp.getWidth(),dpToPixels(this,20)); //or some dp
```

Comment: ha, thanks man but that went straight over my head. So let me get this straight. I put that method in my class, then I call that method when I scale my bitmap, BEFORE putting it into my imageview. Correct?

Comment: yeah, according to the dp of the textview and button your trying to match

Comment: then you can get the pixels to scale it to